# Controller and action within link_to image_tag don't execute controller code

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, link-to

My link_to looks like this:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(user_likes_selection.page_picture, :image_id =>     
user_likes_selection.id, :controller => :preferences_controller, 
:action => :checked_average_with_profile) %>
```

My controller, preferences_controller, has a method called checked_average_with_profile, which, as far as I can tell, is not being called when I click the image.

The html code that is generated from the link_to is

```
<img>
<a href="/preferences"><img action="checked_average_with_profile" alt="Soul_surfer_film"     
controller="preferences_controller" height="70%" image_id="3254" 
src="/assets/soul_surfer_film.jpg" width="70%" /></a>
</img>
```

Why isn't the controller code executed when the image is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in cases like these, it's easier to read the code if you use the block form of `link_to`

```
<%= link_to { :image_id => user_likes_selection.id, :controller => :preferences, :action => :checked_average_with_profile } do %>
  <%= image_tag(user_likes_selection.page_picture %>
<% end %>
```

in your routes, you can also pass an `as` option so you can use a named route. assuming your routes looks like

```
match '/preferences/checked_average_with_profile/:image_id' => 'preferences#checked_average_with_profile', as: :check_average_profile
```

you can simplify your link using

```
link_to image_tag(user_likes_selection.page_picture), check_average_profile_path(user_likes_selection.id)
```

Comment: This looks like it should work, but for some reason my app redirects to the root_url instead of preferences_url when the image is clicked. Also, none of the data that my controller specifies is entered into the database. Any suggestions? It basically looks like it does the same thing as before, but this time it reroutes to the root_url.

Comment: that actually depends on the contents of the `checked_average_with_profile` action. can you include that in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Put your paren after `user_likes_selection.id`, not at the end. You're mixing image tag properties with your link_to properties.

Try:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(user_likes_selection.page_picture, :image_id =>     
user_likes_selection.id), {:controller => :preferences, 
:action => :checked_average_with_profile} %>
```

Comment: I moved the paren around to where you specified and still don't get the controller method activated. Also, quick question, do I write :preferences_controller or just :preferences?

Comment: Sorry was late and on my iPad last night.  I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i do in my code.

```
<%=link_to(image_tag(user_likes_selection.page_picture), check_average_profile_path(user_likes_selection.id)) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(user_likes_selection.page_picture), url_for({:controller => 'preferences_controller', :action => 'checked_average_with_profile', :image_id =>  user_likes_selection.id}) %>
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally solved my problem by adding a collection with my action in resources:

```
resources :preferences do
  collection do
    get 'save_new_scores_to_profile'
    get 'checked_average_with_profile'
  end
end
```

Then, I modified my view code so that I could pass the image_id variable along to the controller.

```
<%= link_to image_tag(user_likes_selection.page_picture,
    checked_average_with_profile_preferences_path(:image_id => 
    user_likes_selection.id) %>
```

In my controller, I made sure to grab the image_id with params and put a redirect_to at the end:

```
def checked_average_with_profile
  params[:image_id]
  redirect_to preferences_url
end
```

If you have this problem, the key parts are passing the id (whatever that may be) within parenthesis of the controller path you specify and using a COLLECTION instead of a MEMBER in your routing file.